# Read files from directory using BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I wrote a code to read a files from a directory.
The directory contain many files. Firstly, I count the number of the files in the directory, then I would like to count number of lines in the files that have as extension: `.info` and `.data`

My code is the following:

```
   public void checkEmptyEntryFileLoader(String directory) {
        File name = new File(directory);
        String filenames[]=name.list();
        long countFile = 0;
        long countLineData = 0;
        long countLineInfo = 0;

        for(String filename:filenames){
            //System.out.println(filename);
            countFile++;
        }
        System.out.println(countFile); // this bloc worked well

        File files[]=name.listFiles();
        for(File file:files){
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if(fileName.endsWith("data")) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                        countLineData++;
                    }
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

             if(fileName.endsWith("info")) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                        countLineInfo ++;
                    }
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(countLineInfo );

        }
    }
```

I got as error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: my_file_name.data (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

The error concerns `the FileReader`, it accept only the `string`, and the `filename` is a `String`

Do you have some idea please ?
Thank you

Comment: I think you should use `getPath` or `getAbsolutePath` instead of `getName` https://www.baeldung.com/java-path

Comment: File.getName returns [a path which is different from the File object’s path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getName()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `filename` in `FileReader()`, try passing `file`.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

My answer assumes that the error that you have given as output is stack trace printed in the try-catch block and not the error that you get when you try to compile/run the code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @SARVESH TANDON looks like will fix your issue and note that you scan the filesystem twice.

Consider using NIO and streams to scan large file systems, as `File.list` / `File.listFiles` perform very badly when number of files get big, or you need to scan deeper as they need to be repeated.

Here is example of code using NIO. It uses a filter to restrict the search to only files of the right extension, and you can vary the find `depth=1` parameter to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for deep scans, and handles exceptions:

```
Path dir = Path.of(directory);
long[] counts = new long[3]; // FILES, MATCHFILES, LINECOUNT
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(dir, 1, (p, a) -> ++counts[0] > 0 && a.isRegularFile())) {
    stream.filter(p -> { String fn = p.getFileName().toString();
        return (fn.endsWith("data") || fn.endsWith("info"))  && ++counts[1] > 0; })
    .forEach(p -> {
        try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(p)) {
            long count = lines.count();
            counts[2]+=count;
            System.out.println("path: "+p+" lines:"+count);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(io);
        }
    });
}
System.out.println("Total files: "+(counts[0]-1));  // dir is counted too
System.out.println("Match files: "+counts[1]);
System.out.println("Total lines: "+counts[2]);
```